# Mounting NFS share locally?

Tags: mount, nfs, openbsd

I share a directory on my OpenBSD server using NFS, with my /etc/exports containing

```
/export -mapall=nobody:nobody -network 192.168 -mask=255.255.0.0
/export -mapall=nobody:nobody -network 10.8.0 -mask=255.255.255.0
```

I can mount this share perfectly from other hosts in my network, but when trying to mount the share locally on the server itself using

```
mount 127.0.0.1:/export /var/www/export
```

I get the error

```
mount_nfs: can't access /export: Permission denied
```

Can you mount NFS shares on the same computer that exports them at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, you simply need to add an entry

```
/export -mapall=nobody:nobody 127.0.0.1
```

exporting it to your local host. The reason I thought this was not the solution is that I tried to mount a subdirectory with

```
mount 127.0.0.1:/export/public /var/www/export
```

which gives the same error message as above. To be able to also mount subdirectories, you must add

```
/export -alldirs -mapall=nobody:nobody 127.0.0.1
```

instead of the above line.

Comment: You could avoid using localhost and a localhost export by using 192.168.x.x instead. But I don't know what you're trying to achieve with such configuration.

Comment: But then it would be exported on the whole LAN, not just locally. That's obviously not what I want for security reasons.

Comment: Ok, it's a new constraint I didn't know. I really don't see what you want to achieve as NFS is made to share filesystem on the network, not to be closed on the same machine that exports filesystems. If you want to manage access restrictions to disks/partitions/filesystems, there are better means than using -mapall option in /etc/exports

Comment: On OpenBSD, there is not "mount bind". The workaround is to export it locally using NFS, and to mount this local NFS share locally.